# Hebrew “work” calendar PDFs ... where?

Tags: product-recommendation, gentiles, passover

Many years ago I came across a nice PDF that listed yontif dates for the coming years. It was an easy way to share a long-distance heads-up of when I’d be out of the office and “unplugged”, without the clutter of holidays like Chanukah when work is permitted.

Where would I find such a thing today?

Comment: you could make one https://www.hebcal.com/hebcal/

Comment: That’s the closest I’ve found, but the result still needs a bunch of edits and explanation. What I remembered (and am seeking) was a “work forbidden” calendar for the office that stayed closed to the essentials. For example, it omitted chol hamoed, which last I saw HebCal couldn’t do.

Comment: You could make this list yourself to your exact specifications in about 15 minutes.

Comment: I'm guessing it probably doesn't exist because there are a lot of different levels of work being permitted. For example, Shabbos/Yom Tov have the most restrictions on work. Chol HaMoed is somewhat less restrictive, but there are still quite a few prohibitions. Then there are days like Purim / Tisha B'Av where work is somewhere between strongly discouraged and actively prohibited. And then there are days like Chanukah where AFAIK there's no prohibition of work.So it's never as simple as permitted/forbidden.

Comment: @Daniel Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this calendar](https://cdn.fedweb.org/fed-66/2/Jewish%2520Calendar1.pdf) may be the closest to what you need. Most of the holidays listed are non-work allowed days except for Purim and Chanukah.

Other than that, I agree with the various ideas mentioned in the comments. Hebcal has several customization options, but, I don't think there's one that will focus on only the "complete" non-work days without including Hol Hamo'ed, etc.

But, you can easily export this to Excel format, and in a few minutes delete the rows that you don't need. Personally, I like doing this as MS Outlook very easily imports Excel formatted files, and I get all these items appearing in my Outlook calendar.

Comment: That has what I asked for. The “non-work” holidays are indicated with asterisks. Thanks!